# Is php pdo lastInsertId function safe?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following simple transaction

(1) user submit some data ->

(2)get data from user ->

(3)insert data to table ->

(4)get inserted row id (i.e lastinsertedId())

What happen when two or more users simultaneously access this case?

Whose row id return?

Comment: The lastInsertId is related to the id or the row this session/connection added with the last INSERT command successfully executed i.e. It is only related to what THIS script did

Comment: if it runs in `transaction` it should be safe from *simultaneous access*.

Comment: @BagusTesa Transaction is not relevant in this case

Comment: sorry distracted on *simple transaction* part..